# Can't provide environment variable from Webpack config to Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

In my config for Webpack I have the following.

```
var config = require("./webfig");
config.module = config.module || [];
config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "Hazaa": "Shazoo" }));
module.exports = config;
```

However, in the TS file, when I try to access it using the line below, the transpiler complains that such a thing isn't available. I'm not entirely certain how to troubleshoot it and googlearching produced not much of value for this specific issue (as far I've recognized the diagnostics properly).

How do I access *Hazaa* in my TypeScript code?

**Edit**

Based on the comments, I've introduced the following changes.

```
config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({ "Hazaa": JSON.stringify("Shazoo") }));
```

A file called *app.d.ts* is created in the same directory as the pre-existing *index.d.ts* was. It contains only `declare var Hazaa: string;` and I'm referring to it from *typings.json* like this.

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.9.7+20161130133742",
    "app": "file:./typings/app.d.ts"
  }
}
```

I also referred to it from *tsconfig.json* section *files* as follows.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./source/application",
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "typings/app.d.ts"
  ],
  "include": [ "source/**/*" ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

Nothing helps - when I go `console.log(Hazaa)` in the constructor of my component, I get the compile time error saying that the name can't be found.

Comment: Aside from [Jaganathan Bantheswaran's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43066808/2587435), you also need to use `JSON.stringify("Shazoo")` or `'"Shazoo"'`

Comment: Are you actually saying that I have to **stringify a string**? It's like `(bool)true`...

Comment: Let say you have `console.log(Hazaa)`. That will get replaced with `console.log(Shazoo)`. Get why you need to use the quotes?

Comment: Yes. Still confused if I have to manually edit my *.d.ts* files. Those will be regenerated pretty regularly...

Comment: Not really sure what you mean. What I said, you should do in your webpack config DefinPlugin. Not sure what that has to do with definition files.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The answer you referred to in your original comment talks about editing the *.d.ts* file also. The typings get regenerated on regular basis in my project so that would need a better approach.

Comment: Well, just to see it work, just add that declaration in the file where are you using the variable. As far as  a global solution so that you don't need to add it to every file, you can create a definition file just for globals like this one. I am not sure what generated defintions you are talking about. If you are creating a library, that I understand. But for an application, there really should be no definitions generated.

Comment: The definition file you create youself (see [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43066450/cant-provide-environment-variable-from-webpack-config-to-angular-2/43066808#comment73217971_43066808)), should not conflict with any generated typings.

Comment: @peeskillet Hey, how did you obtain a link a **comment**?! I've never been able to get it. Replies and questions, sure, but not comments.

Comment: I don't know if there's an easier way, but I just looked at the [guy's profile -> activity tab -> all actions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/744534/jaganathan-bantheswaran?tab=activity) and copied the link location from the comment

Comment: OK, I've tried the suggestions and made an amendment to the question. Care to take a look?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) will help

Comment: @peeskillet Regrettably, no. I've read it a number of times but I simply can't see hwo it resolves my issue. Might be me not used to configuring TypeScript stuff. Probably, even... Of what I understand, the config I have at the moment doesn't successfully reach the definition of *Hazaa* stated in the *app.d.ts* file. But I have no idea how to troubleshoot it further. (*@types* etc. that your comment linked too speak of **limiting** the set of available types, as far I could tell). I'd love to get more help.   :)

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong about the link. But I just tried it and it works when adding it to the `files` like you did in your post. Maybe try `"./typings/index.d.ts"`. I don't know. I was able to get it work just fine. I just clone the quickstart, adding a `typings/index.d.ts` to the root of the project (with the variable declaration) and added `"../typings/index.d.ts"` to the `"files"`. I used '../` because in the quickstart, the tsconfig is in the src and I had the typings in the root

Comment: I though I might have gotten lucky because the quickstart doesn't use webpack, but I did the exact same thing with [this starter project](https://github.com/preboot/angular-webpack) and it works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As TypeScript doesn't know about the webpack global variables (variables defined with DefinePlugin) which is injected into the code when you build the project hence it gives an error. You have to tell TypeScript that the `Hazaa` is a variable of type string which would be evaluated at build time.

So declare the `Hazaa` with your .d.ts file.

```
declare var Hazaa: string;
```

Comment: Where is the appropriate location for that declaration? I mean, how do I declare it so that it automatically gets into my *x.d.ts* file? Or are you saying that I have to do that manually? My *typings* gets rebuilt every now and then so that'd be a pain...

Comment: this declaration could be at your `app.d.ts`. Check this https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3169-adding-custom-typings-files-d-ts-in-an-angular-2-typescript-application.htm.

Comment: Still not quite there. I've read the blog and made some changes (please view the edit in the question).